# How to reset state beforeEach/afterEach jest test?

Tags: jestjs

My components all needed to be wrapped by a state provider in order for them to work, so when I render each component for testing I wrap them in the state provider. Like so:

```
<StateProvider>
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Component_Being_Tested />
  </ThemeProvider>
</StateProvider>
```

The issue I have is that when a component changes state during its test, it doesn't reset the state back to its initial state before the next test runs. This causes many tests to fail.

For example, I have a password input component that includes a 'show/hide password' button. When clicked, it toggles a boolean state value `showPassword`. The initial state is set to `false`, which results in the input type being 'password'. On the first click, it changes the state to `true` and the component changes the input type to 'text'.

When I run a test on this component that involves clicking the button, the first test runs just fine. However after this first test is run, the state for `showPassword` remains as `true` instead of resetting back to its initial `false` value.

Therefore if I run another test that involves clicking the button, the test will fail as clicking the button will toggle the `showPassword` state back to its initial `false` whereas the test is expecting it to change to `true`.

I've tried creating a function that resets state and running it in beforeEach(), like so:

```
beforeEach(() => useContext(Store).dispatch(resetState()));
```

However it fails as useContext is a React Hook and can only be called within a function component.

How else can I reset state before/after each test?

Comment: // Critical to import this to clean the DOM between tests, otherwise the tests will fail.
`import 'react-testing-library/cleanup-after-each'`
Note, this exists in newer versions of react-testing-library. I am using version ^6.0.0 where this is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you would use [React Testing Library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library) you could use `afterEach(cleanup)`.

Besides that, I would change your component architecture. Split it into [display and container components](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#presentational-and-container-components). That way you can explicitly test the display (presentational) component by controlling its state in the test. And you can test the container components using functional and/or E2E tests. Here is a great [guide for testing React](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/unit-testing-react-components-aeda9a44aae2).

Comment: I'm actually using react-testing-library but it's not cleaning up the state.

I've already split my components in containers (to handle logic) and layouts (to handle presentation) but my container needs to run a few functions and pass down the results into layout first.

Comment: @GCM Do you use a new render for each test? That could also cause state not being resetted.

Comment: Yep, new render for each test. I've wrapped the components in a custom render (https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup#custom-render) but even if I remove the custom render and add the providers directly into the test render I still have the same issue.

Comment: hey there @Jake ,
Did you finally solve this issue? how?